# Selenium ChromeDriver exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I am getting following error for my ChromeDriver, and I cannot figure out why.  Chrome is 68 version and chromedriver is 2.41. This throws following error and does not even open the Chrome browser.

```
    Aug 08, 2018 5:08:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 9090
Only local connections are allowed.
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script1533762503012124154837$_run_closure1@2fb69ff6'

at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:382)
at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:371)
at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:111)
at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:927)
at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:59)
at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:46)

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
> cannot parse capability: chromeOptions from unknown error:
> unrecognized chrome option: class   (Driver info:
> chromedriver=2.41.578737
> (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT
> 10.0.163 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds Build info:
> version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time:
> '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z' System info: host: 'CL-', ip:
> '10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version:
> ChromeDriver
```

Here I am not even using any desired Capabilities and I have no idea from where it is getting it.

```
driver = {
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', System.getProperty("user.dir")+'\\src\\test\\resources\\chromedriver.exe')
new ChromeDriver()
```

}

```
<seleniumVersion>3.4</seleniumVersion>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, could you confirm the Selenium version?

Comment: added the version info

Comment: upgrade selenium

Answer (score 0):

I added Guava jar files and it fixed that issue.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>22.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Where did you get that idea from? Can you add a link?